# The right database design for a web synonym application

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, mariadb

I am about to design my database for my synonym web application. If someone is typing a word for example ”important“ you should get some synonyms like ”essential“ or ”necessary“. Since a synonym web app has typically thousands of rows I want to design my database to get the information as fast as possible. For my application I found two possible designs for the synonym database.

| id | word | synonyms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | important | necessary, essential |

| id | parent_id | synonyms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | important |
| 2 | 1 | necessary |
| 3 | 1 | essential |

But I don't know whether they are suitable.

Comment: alright thanks but i have a  little question -> if I would use this methode wouldnt it be a little bit resource unfriendly since it would create way more tables than the first one?

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck in what published presentation of what design method? [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments. "what ideas you have" is not an on-topic question. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) PS [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a normalized design.

Here every colun is indexed and would so deliver fast results

You could also implement a full texts search for word in wordlist

Further enhancements would be to don't use 1,2 and 2,1, but for that the query would be somewhat more complex, and you could insert them at the same time

```
CREATE TABLE Word_list (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   word varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT constraint_word UNIQUE (word))
```

```
INSERT INTO Word_list(word) VALUES('important'),('necessary'),('essential')
```

```
CREATE TABLE synonym(id1 BiginT, id2 Bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY (id1)
        REFERENCES Word_list(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id2)
        REFERENCES Word_list(id)
  , PRIMARY KEY(id1,id2))
```

```
INSERT INTO synonym VALUES(1,2),(1,3)
```

```
SELECT syn.word FROM synonym s JOIN Word_list syn ON s.id2 = syn.id
WHERE id1 = (SELECT id FROM Word_list WHERE word = 'important')
```

| word |
| --- |
| essential |
| necessary |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8i0FRYLt)

Comment: "every column is indexed" -- Not the fastest;  See "composite indexes".  Also, the `id` can be eliminated; since `word` is `UNIQUE`, it would be _better_ for it to be the PK.   "FULLTEXT" -- Why?  Don't use `parent_id`, have the `word`, itself.  Sorry, I have to down-vote.

Comment: @RickJames varchat or text is always slower than bigints, so your answer is much slower than mine

Comment: A secondary index mapping `VARCHAR` to `INT`, then reaching into the table with the `INT` -- this is 2 steps.  If the `VARCHAR` were _either_ the beginning of a composite _and covering_ index, or were the `PRIMARY KEY`, then it is only one step.

Answer (score -1):

If the *only* use for this dataset is to map *from* one word *to* multiple other words, then your first choice is fine.  But be aware, that if you ever need to go the other way, it is messy.

Toss `id` as being wasteful and unnecessary and slowing things down (in *this* case).  So... 2 columns:

```
word VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
synonyms TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(word)
```